# build a complex python dictionary from multiple lists and variables

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I am new to python and programming in general. I looked at a lot of questions about dictionaries, lists, map, lambda, list comprehensions, etc., but I cannot seem to put a specific function together to build the dictionary that I want.

I can describe the dictionary that I want to produce as follows:

```
    #goal: make a dictionary that describes a form

    FORMNAME = 'aspnetForm'
    nicks = ['username','password','submit'] #nicknames I want to use
    names = [FIELD_USERNAME, FIELD_PWD, BUTTON_LOGIN] #field names
    values =  ['myusername','mypass',''] #field values
    types =  ['text', 'password', 'submit'] #control types

    INPUTS = [{nicks[0]:{'name':names[0],'value':values[0],'type':types[0]}},
    {nicks[1]:{'name':names[1],'value':values[1],'type':types[1]}},
    {nicks[2]:{'name':names[2],'value':values[2],'type':types[2]}}]

    LOGINFORM = {'name':FORMNAME, 'input':INPUTS} #this is the final dictionary I want to build
```

Please, impress me with the simplicity and elegance of the best python method to build LOGINFORM so that I may learn!

I want to use this dictionary to populate a form in mechanize. It's the only form I need to populate. I can populate this form the "long" way, but I wanted to learn how to populate it in a systematic way with a dictionary.

My main purpose here is to learn how to populate dictionaries. But I thank you in advance for not suggesting a better way until I learn how to answer my own question.

Comment: Please impress us with any python method you would use to build LOGINFORM so that we are motivated to help you.

Comment: I do not know where to begin. Just read some chapters on lambda, map etc. and haven't absorbed it all. If I saw an example relating to my specific problem I would probably grok it better than the examples in the book. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
LOGINFORM = {'name': FORMNAME, 'input':
     [{nick: {'name': name, 'value': value, 'type': sort}}
       for nick, name, value, sort in zip(nicks, names, values, types)]}
```

I'm avoiding the use of `type` as variable name, because it's a [builtin function/type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type), but actually you can use it here just fine.

Comment: Yep, OP is definitely looking for `zip`.

Comment: GREAT! THANK YOU for answering MY question! Somehow I thought from the examples that I had read that zip only took two arguments.

Comment: 'name' : name should be 'name' : nick and there is a missing '}' at the end. But I appreciate that because it made me look more closely at what is going on! Thanks again. Appreciate it.

Comment: @user1913726 There should have been 4 variables in `zip`, I edited. Does it look correct now?